# 'libsample.so' Not Found error when trying two use more than one cpp in android JNI?

Tags: android, cmake

I'm facing a problem when trying to compile two C++ files, **capplication4.cpp** and **sample.cpp**, in my Android project using JNI and CMake. The two C++ files are in the same directory as CMakeLists.txt. The cpp files basically returns string using jni and works properly. My CMakeLists.txt is as following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)
project("capplication4")
add_library(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
        # List C/C++ source files with relative paths to this CMakeLists.txt.
        sample.cpp
        capplication4.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
        # List libraries link to the target library
        android
        log)
```

I load the two libraries in separate Java classes. The first class that loads capplication4 works as expected. However, the second class, which uses nearly identical code to load sample, crashes and throws the following error:

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.capplication4-1kzs...==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.capplication4-1kzs...==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.example.capplication4-1kzs...==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libsample.so"`

Is there any mistake in the CmakeLists.txt?

Comment: The code you show creates only a single library, `libcapplication4.so`. Where the library `libsample.so` is created?

Comment: I included sample.cpp in add library in CMakeLists.txt.

add_library(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
        sample.cpp
        capplication4.cpp)

Comment: But the error message is about the **library** `libsample.so`, not about the source file `sample.cpp` which you compile as a part of some other library.

Comment: how can I comple to libsample.so. If I create a new fresh project android studio compiles by itself as long as it is included in CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Either by changing the project name in the cmake file or substituting `sample` for `${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} `.